# Why i get this error, Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:5501/locomotive-scroll” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: npm-install, locomotivejs

i'm using locomotive scroll through npm install in my vanilla javascript project.
And I keep getting this error[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoi9o.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUk2y.png)

I don't know what to do
Can anyone help me out how to setup locomotive scroll using npm